# How can I select multiple columns from a Django model?

Tags: django

At the moment I have a query that selects distinct values from a model:

```
Meeting.objects.values('club').distinct()
```

In addition to the 'club' field, I also wish to select a 'time' field.  In other words I wish to select distinct values of the 'club' field and the associated 'time' field.  For example for:

```
CLUB,TIME

ABC1,10:35
ABC2,10:45
ABC2,10:51
ABC3,11:42
```

I would want:

```
ABC1,10:35
ABC2,10:45
ABC3,11:42
```

What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but only if your database backend is **PostgreSQL**. Here how it can be done:

```
Meeting.objects.order_by('club', 'time').values('club', 'time').distinct('club')
```

Look [documentation for `distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)